# Force dialog invalidate after ListView got a new adapter

Tags: android, dialog, adapter, invalidation

I've a ListView inside a Dialog... I have my own adapter for the data, but I also have a Spinner in my Dialog on which the adapter is created/changed.

Now on Spinner selection changed the adapter is created and the ListView's adapter is set to the new adapter...

That all works fine, but my Dialog is not invalidating its layout after the adapter changed, it is always one step behind... Which means, the dialog always has the size it should have had on Spinner selection before...

Edit:
I'm only doing following in the onItemSelected Event of the spinner

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) 
{ 
    if (adapterView.getId() == R.id.spMG) 
    {
        long mg_id = ((MG)sp.getSelectedItem()).getID();
        adapter.clear();
        adapter.addAll(DBDataManager.getExercises(mg_id, true));

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        ((View)lv).invalidate();
    }
}
```

I use an ArrayAdapter and I'm only adding an ArrayList to the adapter.

Comment: Are you running `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: Right now, I'm not using that... I'm anyway calling `listview.setAdapter(...)` but I already tried calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`, but that didn't help...

Comment: Are you running `invalidate()` on the `ListView` afterwards?

Comment: yes, tried that as well... with no success by now...

Comment: What type of `Adapter` are you using?

Comment: Does the `Dialog` layout change when it is selected or used?

Comment: no, only the adapter is changing... (or even only the data itself right now) I even tried not creating a new adapter but clearing the data and adding the new data... and calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` and `listview.invalidate()`afterwards, but that does not help either...

Comment: PS: added the current code to my question...

Comment: What happens if you parse through each entry returned from `getExercises` and add it to the `Adapter` with `add`.  I am of course assuming the rest of you code is correct ;)

Comment: it behaves the same... btw, the data displayed is always correct, just the listview size (or maybe I should say dialog size) is on step behind...

Comment: lol you should have said that from start.  So the `ListView` size is set to `WRAP_CONTENT`?

Comment: yes, somehow... it's adjusting to parent LinearLayout with `layout_height=0 and layout_weight=1`... and the LinearLayout is the main container and is set to `fill_parent`... the behaviour I want is a dialog that is small, if I only have a few items in the list, but extends if the list gets bigger